# how to supply property file as class path

Tags: java, ant, classpath, apache-axis, simplehttpserver

I am creating webservice using AXIS and running this using ANT script.

```
<target if="jars.ok" depends="make.repo" name="start.server">
    <property name="port" value="7070"/>
        <java fork="true" classname="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SimpleHTTPServer">
            <arg value="${build}/repo"/>
            <classpath refid="axis2.class.path"/>
            <arg value="-p${port}"/>
        </java>
    </target>
```

Setted classpath using

```
<path id="axis2.class.path">
        <pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
        <pathelement path="${maven.class.path}"/>
        <fileset dir="${axis2.home}">
            <include name="lib/*.jar"/>
            <include name="resources/*.properties"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>
```

But i am getting error as

```
    [java] log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly [SimpleHTTPServer]
```

What do I need to do to fix this issue, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not add Property files as classpath, just folders and Jar files.

So here include the whole resources folder:

pathelement path="${axis2.home}/resources"

Comment: Thanks A LOT I WAS TOTALLY LOST IN THIS :)